# Excel VBA : How to Compare specific String

Tags: vba, excel

I had came up with some problem that i not sure on how to compare string.

Example

```
Dim DateStart as String
Dim CompareDate as String
DateStart = "01-05-15"
```

In `CompareDate` i type in a value 02-05-15, how can i compare the 01-05 with 02-05?

I do not want to use Dim DateStart as Date.

And also how can i compare Column instead of Row?
The current code i using for comparing row is :

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Range("a1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i compare the 01-05 with 02-05

Since you are doing a `String` match, try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim DateStart As String
    Dim CompareDate As String

    CompareDate = "02-05-15"
    DateStart = "01-05-15"

    If Left(DateStart, (InStrRev(DateStart, "-", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) = _
       Left(CompareDate, (InStrRev(CompareDate, "-", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) Then
        MsgBox "Matches"
    Else
        MsgBox "Doesn't Match"
    End If
End Sub
```

The `InStrRev` function returns the position of the first occurrence of a string (`-` in your case) in another string, starting from the `end` of the string.

Or you could you this simple code

```
If Left(DateStart, 5) = Left(CompareDate, 5) Then
    MsgBox "Matches"
Else
    MsgBox "Doesn't Match"
End If
```

Regarding your second question, I am sorry, I didn't understand what are you trying to achieve. Perhaps if you rephrase it?

**Edit**: Did you mean you want this `SearchOrder:=xlByColumns` instead of `SearchOrder:=xlByRows`

Comment: Thanks alot :) i think you had answered my second question but i had found another way :D ~ but you had let me know a better way :D ~

Answer (score 0):

If you won't use "Dim DateStart as Date" maybe you can use "CDate(DateStart)" while comparing.

If you need a specific format you can use (for example):

```
Format(CDate(DateStart), "dd/mm/yy")
```

Comment: The problem is when i type in in the format "dd-mm-yy" when CDATE() happen will store it to "yy-mm-dd" so everytime my date will become year and year become date... >.<

Comment: You can use Format to obtain the desired output. What format do you need?

Comment: Erm ~ actually i had found out a way but havent try coding yet that is converting my string into array and do comparison ~ might be abit long and abit messy with the code but i think should be working :D ~ thanks alot :D